# Output line number in Rails log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, line-numbers

From the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) on debugging, I found that I can customize output to my log files using this simple method:

```
logger.debug "Person attributes hash: #{@person.attributes.inspect}"
```

I decided use this to track how a variable changes and goes through flow control.

I would like to be able to see the line number of my code where `logger#debug` method was called. Something like this:

```
logger.debug "Person attributes hash: #{@person.attributes.inspect} from line #{LINE_NUMBER_VAR}"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
logger.debug "Person attributes hash: #{@person.attributes.inspect} from line #{__LINE__}"
```

Comment: See my fisrt sentence. Stackoverflow's message parser don't shows two underscores in a row (hides them or eats up somehow else; maybe makes part of message between underscores bold).

Comment: ok great! thanks! I didn't know you meant SO's parsers. so use this: http://dpaste.com/159599/

Answer (score 10):

Use a decorator on Logger:

```
class LoggerDecorator
  def initialize(logger)
    @logger = logger
  end

  %w{debug info warn error fatal}.each do |method|
    eval(<<-eomethod)
      def #{method}(msg)
        @logger.#{method}(position) {msg}
      end
    eomethod
  end

  private
  def position
    caller.at(1).sub(%r{.*/},'').sub(%r{:in\s.*},'')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

As of Rails 5, this is now baked in via:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.verbose_query_logs = true
```

See [the documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#verbose-query-logs) for more